# coffescript - bind function with params

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

```
hookPreview: (tab, textarea) ->
  $(tab).bind "click", preview($(textaread).val()) ->
    false
```

of course it doesn't act as expected: `preview(...)` is not a function. The [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) didn't point out a way that I can pass params to `preview`.

**Edit**:

There's also something wrong with bootstrap's tab control:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#edit" data-toggle="tab" id="edit-tab">Edit</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#preview" data-toggle="tab" id="preview-tab">Preview</a></li>
</ul>
<!-- panel for tabs -->
<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="edit">
        <!-- textarea -->
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="preview">PREVIEW</div>
</div>
```

With `hookPreview`'s existence tabs couldn't switch, but was fine when new handler not bind to it. No errors in console, though.

Comment: Try `hookPreview: (tab, textarea) ->
  $(tab).bind 'click', (->
    $(textaread).val()
    return
  ), false`

Comment: What is `preview($(textaread).val()) ->` supposed to express?!

Comment: Offtopic. I do think `$(tab).bind` is not `Function.prototype.bind` but `jQuery.prototype.bind` which is a different beast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Big stab in the dark here... you want to call the function `preview` with the value of `textaread` on the `click` event? Then:

```
hookPreview: (tab, textarea) ->
  $(tab).bind "click", preview.bind null, $(textaread).val()
```

This reads the value of `textaread` *at the time the event handler is bound*. It also returns whatever `preview` returns, not `false`. To a) `return false` and/or b) read the value of `textaread` *at the time the event is triggered*, write a simple callback wrapper:

```
hookPreview: (tab, textarea) ->
  $(tab).bind "click", ->
    preview $(textaread).val()
    return false
```

Comment: I'm sure multiple handlers can bind to the same "click" but after doing this the tab is not switching, which was done by bootstrap's script.

Comment: Is that a followup question? Because I have absolutely nowhere near enough context to respond to that.

Comment: could they be relevant in any way? If not I'll just close this topic. Thanks.

Comment: Again, no idea what to say here without context. Open a new question, it doesn't sound like it's relevant to this question here.

Answer (score 0):

Putting the `$(textaread).val()` part into the brackets of the `preview` function leads to calling the function, not defining it, thus failing since the function has not been defined.
Yet I don't see any sense in passing the value as a parameter - why not just get it, when the event handler fires:

```
hookPreview: (tab, textarea) ->
  $(tab).bind "click", preview() ->
    textValue = $(textaread).val()
    return false
```

Comment: `preview() ->` has a distinctly different meaning than `preview () ->` or `preview ->`... I'd say the latter two are more likely.